How to add a variance on time series panel
I have data stored in a table, where I have a value, and it’s variance, and I would like to know if it is possible to add the variance in Grafana, to build a legend like in the print where it has ± 1 ppb


I don't racall something like this being possible. But you can plot two graphs: min and max (maybe in addition to existing one), and fill area between them.

Well, that being the case, I think I'll just put the caption indicating the possibility of the error
